# org mode - ipython code block doesn't work

Tags: org-mode

I try to use ob-ipython in org mode.

1. Install ob-ipython module.
2. Add below configuration to enable ob-ipython.

   (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
    '(
      (ipython . t)
      ))
3. Write sample code block in org file.

`#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session :results output drawer
    print "hello"
    #+END_SRC`

4. Press C-c C-c to run this code block,but got a warning as below:

`Warning (python): Python shell prompts cannot be detected.
    If your emacs session hangs when starting python shells
    recover with ‘keyboard-quit’ and then try fixing the
    interactive flag for your interpreter by adjusting the
    ‘python-shell-interpreter-interactive-arg’ or add regexps
    matching shell prompts in the directory-local friendly vars:
      + ‘python-shell-prompt-regexp’
      + ‘python-shell-prompt-block-regexp’
      + ‘python-shell-prompt-output-regexp’
    Or alternatively in:
      + ‘python-shell-prompt-input-regexps’
      + ‘python-shell-prompt-output-regexps’`

What's wrong with my steps?

Comment: What is the setting of `python-shell-interpreter` and `python-shell-interpreter-interactive-arg`?

Comment: python-shell-interpreter =  "python" and python-shell-interpreter-interactive-arg "-i".

Comment: Shouldn't `python-shell-interpreter` have value "ipython"? It seems to work here, but YMMV. Probably the most useful thing you can do though is instrument the function `org-babel-execute:ipython` for edebug and step through it looking for problems.